# set filename on Post with python requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I want to set the name of a file I'm uploading via requests module.

```
files = {'filename': open('myfileXXAAAZZZD','rb')}
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", files=files)
```

It is possible with curl but don't know if requests support's [this](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2007-03/0032.html):

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), the values of the `files` dict can be tuples with filename and content as the first of possibly more elements. So something like

```
files = {'fieldname': ('filename.any', open('myfileXXAAAZZZD','rb').read())}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, missed that, was expecting a dict/json like structure