# How to extract filename using bytes (not UploadFile) in fastAPI

Tags: python, http-post, fastapi

I defined this endpoint using FastAPI:

```
@app.post("/detect/")
def predict(request: Request,  file: bytes = File(...)):

    return f"Filename is {file.name}"
```

and I am testing that endpoint this way:

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/detect"
file = 'myimage.jpg'
f = open(file, 'rb')
files = {"file": (f.name, f, "multipart/form-data")}   

response = requests.request("POST", url,  files=files)

print(response.text)
```

So, I would like the response to be "Filename is myimage.jpg", but `file.name` is not defined.
Which is the correct way to get the file name inside the endpoint? I know I can use `UploadFile` instead of bytes, but in this particular case, I would like to keep `bytes` because of other operations I need to do inside the endpoint.

Comment: Is this what are you searching https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53143852/set-filename-on-post-with-python-requests ?

Comment: You're typing `file` as `bytes`. Instead type it as `UploadFile` as shown in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#file-parameters-with-uploadfile

Comment: Only `UploadFile` allows you to access file metadata

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Upload File using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048825/how-to-upload-file-using-fastapi)